# API Design: Update Response

Tags: api, http, rest, put

I'm designing an HTTP REST API.

Let's say, to update a user's email, I make a PATCH request to `/me`.

What (if any) should be the response body on success?

Comment: Does anyone know how Rails handles this?

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the response body. See [RFC 5789 - PATCH Method for HTTP. 2.1. A Simple PATCH Example](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789).